# How to detect server js and css file changed with out refresh the page

Tags: jquery, html, version, browser-cache

How can we know that the server js and css file changed without refresh the page.

we have implemented versioning in our project and when user will refresh the page it will get all the updated js and css files.

But my client saying is there any way that user can be notify that to get latest version please refresh the page if there is any js and css changed.

actually our site is used in mobile app. sometime user does not close the app for so many days. so that user might not get all the latest changed on their app.

to over come from these type of issue we think to notify user that js and css files changed on the server please refresh the page or close and open the app.

Comment: you can use some ajax to bind the server for versions and trigger a refresh/restart

Comment: How do you implement file versioning?

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev: We have merged all the css and Js files and we are manually changing the version of that one file

Answer (score 0):

You could try to record version changes in a database and the make an ajax call from the app to your server to find out if the version on the phone is different from the one on the server.

If it is, you may prompt the user to refresh the page or you may automatically do so yourself

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the concept of the [HTML5 Application Cache](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp) is here a solution. It is more about the use as an offline application. But with the updating the cache you could do what you want to do.

Comment: I think manifest file is not working in FF and also its not supported in most of the browser. We can't implement this one.
even we have tried this but to get the latest js we need to refresh the page 2 times which is bad for user experience.:(